# Need Change active class in tab ( react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I click Second page,after reload page, all tabs get class CURRENT, How to fix this? How to disable current class on first TAB ?
If i remove activeClassName="current", After Reloading current class switch to first tab, but I saw second tab content

```js
 import React from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory,IndexLink } from 'react-router'




class Tabs extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              index: ''                
        };
        this.onclick = this.onclick.bind(this);
    }

    onclick(index) {
        this.setState({index});
    }

    getListItem(){
        let numbers = this.props.menuitems;
        let listItems = numbers.map((item,index) =>
                <li

                  onClick={this.onclick.bind(this, index)} key={index}>

          <Link to={item.link} activeClassName="current"
           className={index == this.state.index? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}>{item.linkName}</Link>
                  </li>
        );
        return listItems;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="tabs" >{this.getListItem()}</ul>
                <div className="tabs-header-stripe"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Tabs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the scenario u described, you need a `stateful component` instead of `stateless function component`. Store the index of current tab in state variable and update it inside `onclick` method, during the `rendering` compare the index of state variable with the index of item, if they are same then apply the class. Try this a similar example, it should work in ur case also:

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              index: ''                
        };
        this.onclick = this.onclick.bind(this);
    }

    onclick(index) {
        this.setState({index});
    }

    getListItem(){
        let numbers = this.props.menuitems;
        let listItems = numbers.map((item,index) =>
                <li style={{color: this.state.index==index?'red': 'black'}} className={this.state.index == index ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"} onClick={this.onclick.bind(this, index)} key={index}>{index}-{item.number}</li>
        );
        return listItems;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="tabs" >{this.getListItem()}</ul>
                <div className="tabs-header-stripe"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

React.render(<HelloWidget menuitems={[{number:0, index:0}, {number:1, index:1}, {number:3, index:3}]}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

check the `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/27po3p4b/

Comment: yes you have to export it, everything is same just replace tab function by tab class and use the above code. it will work.

Comment: just want to know, have u ever created any stateful component ?? if not will give u some link to know how it works and how to create.

Comment: please give a link

Comment: And now pagination not change, pages. How insert in right way Link to={number.link} activeClassName="current"
     className={index === 0 ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}>{number.linkName}</Link>

Comment: <Link to={item.link}></Link> insert this inslide LI but not helps

Comment: `<Link to={number.link} activeClassName="current" className={index == this.state.index? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}>{number.linkName}</Link>`

Comment: activeClassName='current' is fixed for all li ?? what u want to change activeClassName or className ?

Comment: no just for A element, Can you update your full code please

Comment: you Can remove activeClassName="current", if it's no need to use. The idea is to swtich beetween tabs

Comment: Just need that <li><a class="current"></a><li>

Comment: `code` let listItems = numbers.map((item,index) =>
                <li
                 className={this.state.index == index ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}
                  onClick={this.onclick.bind(this, index)} key={index}>

          <Link to={item.link} activeClassName="current"
           className={index == this.state.index? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}>{item.linkName}</Link>
                  </li>
        ); `code` do this but, When I swtich to second tab, and reload page all tabs are ACTIVE

Comment: except the reload part, is everything working as u expected ?? because for reload thing u have to handle it separately that i will tell

Comment: I updated my code, in Post, this codes run for me, exept reloading, please check

Comment: Can you help with reloading?

Comment: Do this with jqwery `$( document ).ready(function() {

if ($( "ul.tabs li:nth-child(2) a" ).hasClass("current")) {

$( "ul.tabs li a" ).first().removeClass("current");  

}

    }); ` if you have idea how to do this with react, I will be very glad

Comment: check the `pastebin` link for full code, i added i react life cycle method and on page reload set the index again, try this n let me know if it works: http://pastebin.com/6E7Ej8Ww

Comment: If we move from another page to page with tabs, any link not active

Comment: there I create video, you can see what happens https://youtu.be/nZb9m6XWWsk

Answer (score 0):

the className current is only on the first tab because you are checking if index === 0 (first tab) and if true - you are adding the current class.

You need to keep a state of activeTabIndex and on your onClick function change the activeTabIndex to the right index.

and then you can check

```
className={index === this.state.activeTabIndex ? "tab-link current" : "tab-link"}
```

Comment: because u r using a `stateless component`, and above code u can use only in `stateful component`.